How to use a token through out an API
I am having trouble with what I believe is asynchronous functions. I have some end points pointing towards a host with some requests to get a token from my login data, and another get request that uses that token to retrieve information about my profile.
The issue I believe I am having is that the login get request runs before my token is actually saved to my header variable. Is someone able to explain a way that I can wait for the token to be received before my API sends any other requests out?
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true });
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();

const username = process.env.USERNAME
const password = process.env.PASSWORD
let token
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
    headers : {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})


async function login() {
    const response = await instance.post('/login', {username, password})
    token = response.data['token'];
    console.log(token);
}

async function me() {
    const response = await instance.get('/me')
    console.log(response.data);
}

login().then(me())


You're creating your axios instance before your token is assigned. When you define your Authorization header, token is still undefined, therefore axios sends undefined as your Bearer token with each request. You need to update the headers after login() completes.

Thanks for the response but I am still confused why the headers are not updated if I am updating token in the login function. @noassl

That's because when you call axios.create(), you pass in the value that is assigned to token at that moment. Afterwards, your login() function eventually updates token to the acquired value. However, axios.create() is not called again. That means your axios instance is still the "old" one that was created when token was still undefined. You can update the default request headers of your axios instance after the login request like so: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '<token>';. (https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults)

@noassl was correct with their comment. The real issue I was running into was with my incorrect assignment of the token. I changed the code to modify the instance properly.
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true });
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();

const username = process.env.USERNAME
const password = process.env.PASSWORD
let token: string
let instance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.URL
})

async function login() {
    const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.URL}/login`, {username, password})
    token = response.data['token'];
    instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    console.log(token);
}

async function me() {
    const response = await instance.get('/me')
    console.log(response.data);
}

login().then(me())


You've correctly identified the problem, but you don't have the cause quite right yet ;)
The token in your axios instance isn't automatically updated because axios.create() received the value of token, not a reference to the variable. So it doesn't know that you modified the token. Even if it did, creating a second instance most likely isn't what you want to do. Instead, you want to update your existing instance, like I explained in my comment on the original question. So this isn't axios-specific behavior, but a fundamental principle in JavaScript/programming in general.

@noassl The code has been updated and I believe this is the more correct way to do this, thanks for the help!

The code provided here -
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
    headers : {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})

will run only once
You need to use interceptors to retrieve and pass the token for each network request.
Reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors
